# В java поменять кодировку текста

Tags: java

Есть файл.txt з данными подскажите как в java поменять кодировку этого файла.

Answer (score 3):

Хотя это немного и противоречит правилам форума, все же выдам из запасников:

```
/**
 * More or less universal codepage convertor
 * @param infile - input file name, if null System.in presumed
 * @param outfile  - output file name, if null System.out presumed
 * @param from - input file codepage as of http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets, if null system wide property assumed
 * @param to - output file codepage as of http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets, if null system wide property assumed
 * @throws IOException if something wrong with files
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if system doesn't support specified codepage
 */
public static void convert(String infile, String outfile, String from, String to)
        throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    // set up byte streams
    InputStream in;
    if(infile != null)
        in=new FileInputStream(infile);
    else
        in=System.in;
    OutputStream out;
    if(outfile != null)
        out=new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    else
        out=System.out;

    // Use default encoding if no encoding is specified.
    if(from == null) from=System.getProperty("file.encoding");
    if(to == null) to=System.getProperty("file.encoding");

    // Set up character stream
    Reader r=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, from));
    Writer w=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, to));

    // Copy characters from input to output.  The InputStreamReader
    // converts from the input encoding to Unicode,, and the OutputStreamWriter
    // converts from Unicode to the output encoding.  Characters that cannot be
    // represented in the output encoding are output as '?'
    char[] buffer=new char[4096];
    int len;
    while((len=r.read(buffer)) != -1)
        w.write(buffer, 0, len);
    r.close();
    w.flush();
    w.close();
}
```

Пример вызова (перекодировка из традиционной китайской в UTF-8):

```
convert("chinese-traditional.txt", "chinese-utf-8.txt", "GB2312", "UTF8");
```